# How to set blog post under event section in Drupal commons

Tags: 7, nodes

I use the [Drupal Commons](https://www.drupal.org/project/commons) distribution. I already created **blog-post** depends under **group section** using **OG_MEMBERSHIP**. Likewise, **blog-post** depends under content type **event**. How to achieve this?

We also have some **event section** (with particular time/date and location), which is used for maintaining some **blog-post** (content type).

[image]

Can anyone provide some insight about how to do this? I.e some procedure or modules for creating such **blog-post** (content type) under event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Entity reference

Not sure if I correctly understand the question, but it sounds to me that using the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module might be the solution you are looking for. Here's a quote from the module's project page:

> Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities

## References

Another option is to consider the [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) module, which provides D7 versions of the 'node_reference' (and 'user_reference') field types, that were part of the [CCK package](https://www.drupal.org/project/cck) in D6.

## Recommended tutorials

If these module don't help for what you're trying to achieve, then reviewing the amazing set of videos to [Learn Organic Groups](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-organic-groups) might help somehow.

Comment: I used reference module in my drupal.Its works for me.. thanks @Pierre.Vriens...

Comment: Great to hear you @Pierre.. Thanks for give some idea about that reference module.Let me your idea for this [Question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/166290/how-to-show-pop-up-event-in-calendar-in-drupal).Dont change calendar module. I update my question