# How to show Pop-Up event in calendar in drupal

Tags: javascript, datetime, 7

I am working on calendar(event) with drupal [commons](https://www.drupal.org/project/commons).

> My requirement is
>   when user mouseover/click on particular date in calendar,it should
>   show event title and event conduct date in a popup.

[image: POPUP EVENT WITH DATE]
Here i attached my view concept

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'calendar';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'Calendar';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Calendar';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['link_display'] = 'page_1';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['query_comment'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'date_views_pager';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['date_id'] = 'month';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'calendar_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['name_size'] = '3';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['with_weekno'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['multiday_theme'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['theme_style'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['max_items'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'calendar_entity';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_field']['id'] = 'title_field';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_field']['table'] = 'field_data_title_field';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_field']['field'] = 'title_field';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_field']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_field']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_field']['link_to_entity'] = 1;
/* Field: Content: Rendered Node */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['id'] = 'rendered_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['table'] = 'views_entity_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['field'] = 'rendered_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['link_to_entity'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['display'] = 'view';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['view_mode'] = 'teaser';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['bypass_access'] = 0;
/* Field: Colorbox: Colorbox trigger */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['colorbox']['id'] = 'colorbox';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['colorbox']['table'] = 'colorbox';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['colorbox']['field'] = 'colorbox';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['colorbox']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['colorbox']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['colorbox']['trigger_field'] = 'title_field';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['colorbox']['popup'] = '[rendered_entity]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['colorbox']['gid'] = 1;
/* Field: Content: Date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['id'] = 'field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['table'] = 'field_data_field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['field'] = 'field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['settings'] = array(
  'format_type' => 'long',
  'fromto' => 'both',
  'multiple_number' => '',
  'multiple_from' => '',
  'multiple_to' => '',
  'show_repeat_rule' => 'show',
);
/* Sort criterion: Content: Date -  start date (field_date) */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_date_value']['id'] = 'field_date_value';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_date_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_date_value']['field'] = 'field_date_value';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'event' => 'event',
);

/* Display: Month */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Month', 'page_1');
$handler->display->display_options['field_language'] = 'fr';
$handler->display->display_options['field_language_add_to_query'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'date_views_pager';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['date_id'] = 'month';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['link_format'] = 'clean';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'calendar_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['name_size'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['mini'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['with_weekno'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['multiday_theme'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['theme_style'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['max_items'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'calendar_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['colors']['legend'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['id'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['field'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_argument_type'] = 'date';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['add_delta'] = 'yes';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['date_fields'] = array(
  'field_data_field_date.field_date_value' => 'field_data_field_date.field_date_value',
);
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'calendar-node-field-date/month';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'default tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Month';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['tab_options']['type'] = 'normal';
$handler->display->display_options['tab_options']['title'] = 'Calendar';
$handler->display->display_options['tab_options']['weight'] = '0';

/* Display: Week */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Week', 'page_2');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'date_views_pager';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['date_id'] = 'week';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['link_format'] = 'clean';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'calendar_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['calendar_type'] = 'week';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['name_size'] = '3';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['mini'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['with_weekno'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['multiday_theme'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['theme_style'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['max_items'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'calendar_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['id'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['field'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_argument_type'] = 'date';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['granularity'] = 'week';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['add_delta'] = 'yes';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['date_fields'] = array(
  'field_data_field_date.field_date_value' => 'field_data_field_date.field_date_value',
);
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'calendar-node-field-date/week';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Week';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '2';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;

/* Display: Day */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Day', 'page_3');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'date_views_pager';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['date_id'] = 'day';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['link_format'] = 'clean';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'calendar_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['calendar_type'] = 'day';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['name_size'] = '3';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['mini'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['with_weekno'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['multiday_theme'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['theme_style'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['max_items'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'calendar_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['id'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['field'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_argument_type'] = 'date';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['granularity'] = 'day';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['date_fields'] = array(
  'field_data_field_date.field_date_value' => 'field_data_field_date.field_date_value',
);
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'calendar-node-field-date/day';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Day';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '3';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;

/* Display: Year */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Year', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'date_views_pager';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['date_id'] = 'year';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['link_format'] = 'clean';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'calendar_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['calendar_type'] = 'year';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['name_size'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['mini'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['with_weekno'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['multiday_theme'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['theme_style'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['max_items'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'calendar_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['hide_alter_empty'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['id'] = 'field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['table'] = 'field_data_field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['field'] = 'field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['hide_alter_empty'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['settings'] = array(
  'format_type' => 'short',
  'fromto' => 'both',
  'multiple_number' => '',
  'multiple_from' => '',
  'multiple_to' => '',
  'show_repeat_rule' => '',
);
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['group_rows'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['delta_offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['id'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['field'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_argument_type'] = 'date';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['granularity'] = 'year';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['add_delta'] = 'yes';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['date_fields'] = array(
  'field_data_field_date.field_date_value' => 'field_data_field_date.field_date_value',
);
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'calendar-node-field-date/year';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Year';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '4';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['use_ajax'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_ajax'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'date_views_pager';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['date_id'] = 'mini';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'calendar_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['name_size'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['mini'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['with_weekno'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['multiday_theme'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['theme_style'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['max_items'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'calendar_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['id'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['field'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_argument_type'] = 'date';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['add_delta'] = 'yes';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['date_fields'] = array(
  'field_data_field_date.field_date_value' => 'field_data_field_date.field_date_value',
);

/* Display: Upcoming */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Upcoming', 'block_2');
$handler->display->display_options['display_description'] = 'Upcoming events block';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['use_more'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_more'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '5';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'list';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['id'] = 'date_filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['field'] = 'date_filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['operator'] = '>=';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['default_date'] = 'now';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['add_delta'] = 'yes';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['date_fields'] = array(
  'field_data_field_date.field_date_value' => 'field_data_field_date.field_date_value',
);
$translatables['calendar'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Month'),
  t('All'),
  t('Week'),
  t('Day'),
  t('Year'),
  t('Block'),
  t('Upcoming'),
  t('Upcoming events block'),
);
```

Kindly give me some idea for this colorbox concept.I used colorbox module in my drupal but i cant achieve it..

How to achieve it. I tried calendar pop-up but no luck. Is there any plugins for event calender popup or how to show popup in event calendar or Kindly guide me for creating pop-up with drupal commons..

Comment: You can use [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) to create popups in Views result.

Comment: I used colorbox with creating popups in view results .@PominWu kindly give some procedure for creating colorbox in event calendar

Comment: @PominWu.. Here i update my question and use colorbox module also.but no response.Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to build a calendar of Events with Views in [Commons](https://www.drupal.org/project/commons).  You need to install Colorbox by [following the instructions](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox).  To create a view of Events, proceed as follows:

1. Check *Enable Colorbox inline* at `/admin/config/media/colorbox`.
   [image]
2. Add a new view of Events as usual, set *Display format* to the way you want with *fields* (the default is usually *teasers*).
3. Continue and edit the view.  In the *Fields* section, edit *Content: Title* and check *Exclude from display*.  Add a *Content: Date* field, and a few more fields that you want to display in the popup, and likewise check *Exclude from display* for all of them.
4. Add a *Colorbox: Colorbox trigger* field, set its *Trigger field* to *Date*, and edit the *Popup* contents.  You can use replacement patterns in popup contents.
   [image]
5. Save the view.

Comment: @PominWu..i just follow your instruction and create view with calendar its working with event details.but I need  to event link in particular date [Date with custom URL but working wrong](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/08/07/drupal-customize-the-day-link-inside-the-mini-calendar-navigation-block/).

Answer (score 2):

The [Fullcalendar module](https://www.drupal.org/project/fullcalendar) has similar functionality - it allwes you to display event node in popup. By default, there is support for [Colorbox](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox). However, there is also [a patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/1598712) for using Overlay (from Drupal core).

Comment: Here i update my question.kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking at the [Field formatter for colorbox module](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_field_formatter). That module doesn't have a lot of documentation (yet), as confirmed also in some of the issues in its issue queue. And I don't have experience with it myself (yet).

But in [Comment nr 2](https://www.drupal.org/node/2334695#comment-9129325) of [Issue 2334695](https://www.drupal.org/node/2334695), the module maintainer wrote this:

> The field formatter of the [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) module is for images only. [This module here](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_field_formatter) **supports text and computed fields** and comes with some specific options for those field types.

So I think your best bet is to give this module a try, and if needed create an appropriate issue in it's issue queue to get it to work.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens.thank for your effort and make useful idea for me...I tried to create colorbox popup with event calendar..but i need to create popup in every day in month with event listing's and googling with get some [link](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/08/07/drupal-customize-the-day-link-inside-the-mini-calendar-navigation-block/) but it not applicable for my needs